# How to express the sign function as a difference of indicator function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to express the $\textrm{sign}$ function as a difference of indicator function?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\textrm{sign}(x) = 1_{x > 0} - 1_{x < 0}$$